# Regular expression for text with colon sign and enclosed in double courts

Tags: regex, matlab

I have following type of entries in my data

```
"plugin" : "xyz"
"host" : "lmn",
```

I would like to extract xyz and lmn. So far I am using extractafter and extractbefore functions in the following manner

```
hostName(count_host) = cellstr(extractAfter(extractBefore(extractAfter(content, ':'),'",'),'"'));
```

Please advice regular expressions to extract the data for both entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and extract your value from group1,

```
"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RR8BLE/1)**

Python code for same,

```
import re

s = '''"plugin" : "xyz"
"host" : "lmn",'''

print(re.findall(r'"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"', s))
```

Prints,

```
['xyz', 'lmn']
```

Comment: hostName(count_host) = regexp(content, '[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)'). This is how I am recruiting the proposed solution.

Comment: @Yogesh: The value you need to retrieve is from group1, for which I think you need to `tokens` and write your expression something as `hostName(count_host) = regexp(content, '[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)', 'tokens')` I am not very familiar with matlab, so you may have to search a bit how to extract group1 value but this is what I could find quickly. [Check this reference](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html)